# Not getting the id of the clicked name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a jquery code that fetched the name of the users saved in mysql.

```
<script>  
var currentID = null;
function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
      //fetch_chat();
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 fetch_data();
 $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    alert(currentID);
  });
});         
</script>
```

and the select.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
 session_start();
require("config.php");
 $output = '';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users  where name!='$_SESSION[name]'";  
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);  
 $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  

                     <th width="40%">First Name</th>  

                </tr>';  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  

                     <td class="first_name" data-id1="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row["name"].'</td>  

                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  

 }  
 else  
 {  
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
                     </tr>';  
 }  
 $output .= '</table>  
      </div>';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

The problem is that I am not geeting the id of the clicked user. the code is to fetch the data from the table and when clicked on any name it should alert their respective id.

Comment: does that id is there in source code in browser ?

Comment: what is displaying in alert box?

Comment: @irony I am not getting a alert box

Comment: It means that your `currentID`  is null please verify array index `id` with the database columns

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot that `$(document).on()` should work for dynamic elements.  Old answer is attached at the end of the post.

Please check if the `$row['id']` is properly fetched from the server by inspecting element in the browser.  Or you may modify the code so inside the `<td>` it shows `$row['id']` instead of `$row['name']` to see if the `id` is correctly fetched.  Chances are that the `id` field isn't named as `id` in the database - partially why `SELECT *` queries aren't good (autocomplete and SQL errors won't help us if we listed the wrong field!).

In case it is correctly fetched but the handlers seems not working, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24767578/6712483) may help.

#### Old Answer

<strike>For a quickfix, you should put the click handler block inside the `success:` callback of the ajax call, i.e.:</strike>

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#live_data').html(data);
    $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
        currentID = $(this).data("id1");
        alert(currentID);
    });
}
```

Probably the reason why it isn't working is that `fetch_data()` is an ajax call.

So before `$('#live_data')` is populated (after the ajax call succeeded), you have already told the document to attach the click handlers.  The `<td>`s are not there yet!

However, you may not want `fetch_data()` to couple with the click-handler-adding function.  In that case, you may want to attach a `then()` and return a Promise in the `fetch_data()` function.

Hope these links may help:

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
- http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: `$(document).on()` will work for Dynamic elements (added from ajax) Also

Comment: It worked twice in my system but after few days when I run the it wasn't working.

Comment: In that case, if you have a version control, maybe it is worth trying to revert the commits to find the one the broke this existing function?
And, is the `$row['id']` correctly shown in the HTML?